# migrating from eclipse to android studio Error:Android Dex: Unable to execute DX

Tags: android-studio

I was trying to migrate my project from eclipse to android studio and that appear a problem:

```
Error:Android Dex: [NaviDrawerWithPager] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [NaviDrawerWithPager] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson$OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
```

NaviDrawerWithPager was my project name and I am use the library actionbarsherlock
Did anyone have the same problem with or know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have deleted all the repeat .jar and the same problem still exit

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after importing a project to Android-Studio (v2.2.3).

> Error:Android Dex: [Lab3c_FragmentsLabTestPhone] Unable to execute DX
>   Error:Android Dex: [Lab3c_FragmentsLabTestPhone]
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/robotium/solo/ActivityUtils$1;

In the project Dependencies (Module Settings (F4) -> Dependencies), there were two different versions of the same libraries, robotium_solo_5_3_1 and robotium_solo_5_3_11. Removed the first, tried again and the error disappeared.